# Hibernate generates incorrect foreign key constraint for single table inheritance in OneToMany

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have single-table inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "fruit_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Item<T extends Base> extends Base {

    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "fruit_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public T getFruit();
```

with concrete subclass:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("banana")
public class BananaItem extends Item<Banana> {
```

and another:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("orange")
public class OrangeItem extends Item<Orange> {
```

and the two fruit classes hold collections of these items, like in Banana:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<BananaItem> bananaItems;
```

and in Orange:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<OrangeItem> orangeItems;
```

but now, in a test, when I go to make an innocent Banana holding some bananaItems (who have had bananaItem.setFruit(banana) called on them), I get this bizarre FK constraint violation from Hibernate's generated schema used in tests:

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK9QL9Y1RJG59996CUD9NAVCN80: PUBLIC.ITEMS FOREIGN KEY(PARENT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ORANGES(ID)
```

for some reason Hibernate thinks it should have OrangeItems, even though I'm saving a Banana with BananaItems in it! If I modify the `@JoinColumn` for `getFruit()` to use `foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)` then the error goes away, but that feels rather hacky and I could be missing some other subtle problem.

Comment: That is not HBN fault: in your case single column `fruit_id` should refer to `id` columns in two different tables, which in turn means the corresponding records must exist in those tables prior to inserting data

Comment: oh that isn't an issue, Hibernate handles generating IDs perfectly fine

Comment: The error refers to the column `PARENT_ID`, but in the model you posted, I don't see that column mentioned.